# Print an extra space if the value is positive

Tags: julia

I'm trying to get a visually clear output of my program:

```
a = -1234
b =  1234
@printf "a = %s%1.2e" ""  a
@printf "b = %s%1.2e" " " b
```

which gives:

```
a =  1.23e+03
b = -1.23e+03
```

(The point is to add an extra space for positive number)

Now I want to automate it. I tried to write a funtion:

```
function negspace(x::Number)
    if x < 0
        return "", x
    else
        return " ", x
    end
end
```

and print with

```
a = -1234
b =  1234
@printf "a = %s%1.2e" negspace( a )
@printf "b = %s%1.2e" negspace( b )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even simpler is to use the [printf format flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Format_placeholders) to do this directly by putting a space after the `%`:

```
julia> @sprintf("a = % 1.2e", -1234)
"a = -1.23e+03"

julia> @sprintf("b = % 1.2e", 1234)
"b =  1.23e+03"
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env julia

function signspace(x::Number)
    if x > 0
        return @sprintf(" %1.2e", x)
    else
        return @sprintf( "%1.2e", x)
    end
end

a = -1234
b =  1234

println("a = ", signspace(a))
println("b = ", signspace(b))
```

but I'm not sure it is optimal.